# Displaying data of columns and a single average in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do you display entire columns in MySQL simultaneously displaying the average of one column. The problem I incur is that I get the error message Error "Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns" I understand the error but was wondering if  there was a way to display data from the informative columns alongside the average. Here is the query I am using

```
SELECT title_id, type, price FROM titles

union all

SELECT avg(price) FROM titles;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cross join` instead of union:

```
SELECT title_id, type, price, avg_price 
FROM titles
cross join (SELECT avg(price) as avg_price
      FROM titles
     ) as avg_titles
```